# C++ - Vector of Float Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I'm currently attempting to create a vector that holds float arrays. I am having a diffcult time.

I have the following code:

```
float testArray[4] = {20, -3.14/2, 5, -3.14/2};
std::vector<float[4]> inputVector;
std::vector<float[4]>::iterator it = inputVector.begin();
inputVector.insert(it, testArray);
```

I keep getting an error say "array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer" and "invalid array assignment". I tried this same code with a vector of ints (as opposed to a vector of array) and did not have any issue.

I believe there is an underlying issue that I don't understand.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Arrays can not be copied with normal copy-semantics (or moved since C++11), and vectors require that the stored data type is. See e.g. [this `std::vector` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the easiest way to initialize a std::vector with hardcoded elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236197/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-initialize-a-stdvector-with-hardcoded-elements)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). C-style arrays shouldn't generally be used in modern C++ code.

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>

int main()
{
  std::array<float, 4> testArray{{20, -3.14/2, 5, -3.14/2}};
  std::vector<std::array<float, 4>> inputVector;
  std::vector<std::array<float, 4>>::iterator it = inputVector.begin();
  inputVector.insert(it, testArray);
}
```

Read these questions/answers for more information:

- ["Now that we have std::array what uses are left for C-style arrays?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111565/now-that-we-have-stdarray-what-uses-are-left-for-c-style-arrays)
- ["c++11 std::array vs static array vs std::vector"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18868860/c11-stdarray-vs-static-array-vs-stdvector)

---

Note that this will copy the array and all its contents. If you want to  refer to the existing `testArray` instance, create an  `std::vector<std::array<float, 4>*>` and take the address of the instance when inserting it in the vector: `inputVector.insert(it, &testArray);`.

Comment: @tobi303: I'm using `std::array` in place of `float[4]`, not in place of the `std::vector`. C-style arrays have no use in modern C++ code.

Comment: ups sorry, I was a bit fast with posting nonsense ;)

Comment: @VittorioRomeo what about when you are transmitting arrays over something like a serial link? Can I use C-style arrays then?

Comment: @Sam: why wouldn't you be able to use `std::array` in that situation?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Because you on have the std::array.data you don't have any of the ancillary information that the array class stores (size comes to mind).

Comment: @Sam: [yes you have](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/size) - just pass `(array.data(), array.size())` to the function that requires a C-style interface.

Answer (score 1):

How about this :-

```
float t[4] = {20, -3.14/2, 5, -3.14/2};
float *testArray=t;
std::vector<float*> inputVector;
std::vector<float*>::iterator it = inputVector.begin();
inputVector.insert(it, testArray);
```

It would be better if you use `std::array<float, 4>` instead of `in-built arrays`. The problem with your previous code was that you were attempting something like :-

```
float a[4] {1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4};
float b[4] = a;   // illegal conversion of float[] to float*
```

Hence your code used to fail